# Determine Number of Squares a Knight Guards

Tags: java, arraylist, user-input, hashcode

I am having a bit of trouble producing the right output for this assignment and not sure what I am doing wrong.

There are K knights on N x N chessboard and you are to determine how many squares they are guarding. A square is guarded if it is either occupied by a
knight or is reachable by a knight by a single move.
Write a program that reads positive integers N and K and then K positions of knights, and prints the
number of squares that are guarded by these K knights.

[image]

Example of input: `8 2 c 1 e 2`

Corresponding output: `10`

Example of input: `8 6 c 1 e 2 d 4 c 7 f 7 h 6`

Corresponding output: `30`

When I input the first example it works, but when I input the second example it gives me `34`

```
package knightguard;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

public class KnightGuard {

    static class Position {

        int x;
        int y;

        public Position(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public boolean equals(Position p) {
            if (p.x == x && p.y == y) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return x + "," + y;
        }

    }

    ArrayList<Position> knightPositions;
    int size;
    int no_of_knights;

    public KnightGuard(int size, int k, ArrayList<Position> knightPositions) {
        this.knightPositions = knightPositions;
        no_of_knights = k;
        this.size = size;
    }

    public int getSafePositions() {
        Set<Position> safePos = new HashSet<>();
        for (Position p : knightPositions) {
            if (isValid(p.x - 2, p.y - 1)) {
                safePos.add(new Position(p.x - 2, p.y - 1));
            }
            if (isValid(p.x - 2, p.y + 1)) {
                safePos.add(new Position(p.x - 2, p.y + 1));
            }
            if (isValid(p.x + 2, p.y - 1)) {
                safePos.add(new Position(p.x + 2, p.y - 1));
            }
            if (isValid(p.x + 2, p.y + 1)) {
                safePos.add(new Position(p.x + 2, p.y + 1));
            }

            if (isValid(p.x - 1, p.y - 2)) {
                safePos.add(new Position(p.x - 1, p.y - 2));
            }
            if (isValid(p.x - 1, p.y + 2)) {
                safePos.add(new Position(p.x - 1, p.y + 2));
            }
            if (isValid(p.x + 1, p.y - 2)) {
                safePos.add(new Position(p.x + 1, p.y - 2));
            }
            if (isValid(p.x + 1, p.y + 2)) {
                safePos.add(new Position(p.x + 1, p.y + 2));
            }
        }

        return safePos.size();
    }

    private boolean isValid(int x, int y) {
        if (x < 0 || x >= size || y < 0 || y >= size) {
            return false;
        }

        if (knightPositions.contains(new Position(x, y))) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int size = s.nextInt();
        int knights = s.nextInt();
        ArrayList<Position> knightPos = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < knights; i++) {
            int x = s.next().charAt(0) - 'a';
            int y = s.nextInt() - 1;
            knightPos.add(new Position(x, y));
        }

        KnightGuard knightGuard = new KnightGuard(size, knights, knightPos);
        System.out.println(knightGuard.getSafePositions());

        s.close();

    }

}
```

Comment: You counting positions guarded by multiple knights multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

One issue in using this approach is that possible duplicate positions may be generated for different knights. Example; using the picture in the post, the two knights at positions D4 and H6 can BOTH move to the square at F5. Therefore, the posted code will count this position TWICE. In theory, there could possibly be eight (8) knights at eight different positions and all could move to the same square. A check is going to have to be made to eliminate these possible “duplicate’ positions.

I am a little confused by the `KnightGuard` class and the `getSafePositions` method. The `KnightGuard` class has a list of positions, this is the list of the positions of the given knights. However the `getSafePositions` method simply returns the number of different moves all the knights could move from their respective positions. This method does not take into account that the previous knight could also move to the same position as described in the first paragraph.

To simplify things… I feel a class called `Knight` would be a better approach. A Knight would have a `Position` variable to indicate where “THIS” knight is positioned on the board. In Addition, the `Knight` class would contain an `ArrayList` of `Position` objects to indicate all the possible moves this knight can make given its position. A `Knight` should NOT be aware of any other `Knights` and the list of positions it can move to are all the positions it could move to regardless if there is another piece at that position. This list would contain a minimum of two (2) positions and up to a maximum of eight (8) different positions.

When a new `Knight` object is created, the list of possible moves is automatically generated upon instantiation along with its own position on the board, which we will need later.

Below is an example of this `Knight` class. It should be noted that in this class and in the main method, I changed the indexing of the board to start at 1 (a) not zero (0) on the left and moves right and also on the y index where the bottom y index is 1 and moves up. In addition a `SetValidMoves` method is created to allow the list of positions this knight can move, to be changed. This may be needed if another knight occupies one of the positions in this knight's list of guarded positions. This code is not taking advantage of this since we are only interested in the number of guarded squares.

```
public class Knight {

  Position knightPosition;
  ArrayList<Position> validMoves;
  int boardSize;

  public Knight(Position position, int inBoardSize) {
    knightPosition = position;
    validMoves = new ArrayList<Position>();
    boardSize = inBoardSize;
    SetValidMoves();
  }

  public Position GetKnightPosition() {
    return knightPosition;
  }

  public ArrayList<Position> GetValidMoves() {
    return validMoves;
  }
  public void SetValidMoves(ArrayList<Position> newMoves) {
    validMoves = newMoves;
  }

  private void SetValidMoves() {
    int thisX = knightPosition.x;
    int thisY = knightPosition.y;
    // check for bottom moves 2 down 1 left - right
    if (thisY - 2 >= 1) { 
      if (thisX + 1 <= boardSize) { 
        validMoves.add(new Position(thisX + 1, thisY - 2));
      }
      if (thisX - 1 >= 1) { 
        validMoves.add(new Position(thisX - 1, thisY - 2));
      }
    }
    // check for bottom moves 1 down 2 left - right
    if (thisY - 1 >= 1) { 
      if (thisX + 2 <= boardSize) { 
        validMoves.add(new Position(thisX + 2, thisY - 1));
      }
      if (thisX - 2 >= 1) { 
        validMoves.add(new Position(thisX - 2, thisY - 1));
      }
    }
    // check for top moves 2 up 1 left - right
    if (thisY + 2 <= boardSize) { 
      if (thisX + 1 <= boardSize) { 
        validMoves.add(new Position(thisX + 1, thisY + 2));
      }
      if (thisX - 1 >= 1) { 
        validMoves.add(new Position(thisX - 1, thisY + 2));
      }
    }
    // check for top moves 1 up 2 left - right
    if (thisY + 1 <= boardSize) { 
      if (thisX + 2 <= boardSize) { 
        validMoves.add(new Position(thisX + 2, thisY + 1));
      }
      if (thisX - 2 >= 1) { 
        validMoves.add(new Position(thisX - 2, thisY + 1));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With an `ArrayList` of `Knight` objects (`knightsOnBoard`) it is possible to loop thought this list and create an `ArrayList` of `Position` objects (`validMoves`) where each `Position` indicates a position one or more of the knights is guarding. Since duplicates are not wanted, we simply ignore positions that are already in the `validMoves` list.

`knightsOnBoard` is the global list of `Knight` objects

```
private static ArrayList<Position> GetAllDifferentPositions() {
  ArrayList<Position> validMoves = new ArrayList<Position>();
  for (Knight curKnight : knightsOnBoard) {
    for (Position curPos : curKnight.validMoves) {
      if (!validMoves.contains(curPos)) {
        validMoves.add(curPos);
      }
    }
  }
  return validMoves;
}
```

Since the above code uses the `contains` property to check if the position is already in the list `validMoves`, a change is needed in the `Position` class to publicly expose the `equals` method using an Object parameter.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
  if (obj instanceof Position) {
    Position other = (Position)obj;
    if (this.x == other.x && this.y == other.y)
      return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

Now we have an `ArrayList` of `Position` objects that do not have duplicates. Unfortunately, there is one last hurdle to clear. There needs to be a check to see if a `Knight` can move to a square but it is already occupied by another knight. Therefore we will need to remove all the ‘Knight`’s positions in the list of positions the knights can move to.

The reason this must be done is that we need to add all the given `Knight`’s positions to the count since the square the knight is sitting on is also a “guarded” square. Since it is possible this position is already in the list… we need to remove them. In other words, we know a `Knight` will not have “its” own position in its list of moves, however it may have another `Knight`s position in its list of moves.

```
private static void RemoveAllKnightPositions(ArrayList<Position> allPositions) {
  for (Knight curKnight : knightsOnBoard) {
    if (allPositions.contains(curKnight.knightPosition)) {
      allPositions.remove(curKnight.knightPosition);
    }
  }
}
```

Now the list of positions (`finalResults` below) has no duplicates and in addition, we know the list does not contain any of the positions where a knight is sitting. Therefore, the number of guarded squares would be the number of positions in the positions list `finalResults` PLUS the number of knights.

Finally, putting this all together in the main method below. Please note the code changes the indexing order so BOTH x and y start at one (1) and end at `boardSize`. I hope this makes sense and helps.

```
static ArrayList<Knight> knightsOnBoard = new ArrayList<Knight>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
  int boardSize = s.nextInt();
  int knights = s.nextInt();
  for (int i = 0; i < knights; i++) {
      int x = (s.next().charAt(0) - 'a') + 1;
      int y = s.nextInt();
      Knight newKnight = new Knight(new Position(x,y), boardSize);
      knightsOnBoard.add(newKnight);
      System.out.println("Knight at : " + newKnight.knightPosition.x + " " +  newKnight.knightPosition.y);
   }

  ArrayList<Position> finalResults = GetAllDifferentPositions();
  RemoveAllKnightPositions(finalResults);
  System.out.println("Positions: " + (finalResults.size() + knightsOnBoard.size()));
  s.close();  
}
```